# Problems installing gozmq with go get

Tags: go, installation

I was trying to install gozmq with the usual go get:

```
go get github.com/alecthomas/gozmq
```

However, I was having the following error:

```
# pkg-config --cflags libzmq libzmq libzmq libzmq
exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I don't really understand what this error means. Does it mean that its trying to run the command `# pkg-config --cflags libzmq libzmq libzmq libzmq`and its failing because `pkg-config` is not on $PATH? What is `pkg-config` anyway and why do I need it? how do I install it?

I tried brew installing pkg-config but it didn't work and it threw me the following error:

```
# pkg-config --cflags libzmq libzmq libzmq libzmq
Package libzmq was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libzmq.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libzmq' found
Package libzmq was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libzmq.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libzmq' found
Package libzmq was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libzmq.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libzmq' found
Package libzmq was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libzmq.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libzmq' found
exit status 1
```

not sure why that happened.

---

EDIT:

As the first answerer suggested, I did:

```
brew install --devel zeromq
```

however, I get the following error after I do `go get github.com/alecthomas/gozmq`
Error:

```
# github.com/alecthomas/gozmq
37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_SWAP'
37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC'
37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP'
38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_HWM'
```

seem to be "normal" go errors/warning. But they come from a library I got online. I am not sure what to do, if I should fix them myself or what I should to to address it or e-mail the original developers/community or git issue etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the development versions of those libraries.

```
$ brew install --devel zeromq
```

According to [issue 98](https://github.com/alecthomas/gozmq/issues/98), if you're using `zeromq v3.x` you need to use :

```
go get -tags zmq_3_x github.com/alecthomas/gozmq
# or if you're using 4x 
go get -tags zmq_4_x github.com/alecthomas/gozmq
```

Check the [README](https://github.com/alecthomas/gozmq#installing).

Comment: it's zeromq not libzmq, my bad.

Comment: I think I successfully installed it? But it throws me `# github.com/alecthomas/gozmq
37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_SWAP'
37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC'
37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP'`
38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_HWM'` is that normal? should I worry about it? how do I test if it did indeed install?

Comment: That seems like a bug in the package itself, report it on their github issue tracker.

Comment: last question, how was I suppose to know I was suppose to do `brew install --devel zeromq` to fix the bug?

Comment: "Package libzmq was not found in the pkg-config search path." means the zeromq package wasn't installed on your computer, so you just had to install it, finding the right now is just a matter of googling, also check the update I just posted.

Comment: it does mention that in issue 98 (https://github.com/alecthomas/gozmq/issues/98) that version 4 might not work. Is there a way to install a specific version with homebrew?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used it.